# c++: Arrays, too many initializers

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
char somearray[6][5] = {{'M','a','r', 't', 'i', 'n'},
                        {'L','i','a','m','z'}};

for(int j=0; j<5; j++ ){
    for (int k = 0; k<5; k++ ){
        cout<< somearray[j][k];
    }
}



return 0;
}
```

error:

```
 test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 test.cpp:11:29: error: too many initializers for ‘char [5]’
     {'L','i','a','m','z'}};
```

There is something I don't understand, I have one error, I tried to mess with the multi dimensional array initializer however I keep getting the same too many initalizers  error. I followed a c++ tutorial and I keep getting that error. I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first element `somearray[0]` has 6 elements

```
{'M','a','r', 't', 'i', 'n'}
```

instead of 5. Remember that `somearray[6][5]` declares a bi-dimensional array with 6 rows and 5 columns, or, equivalently, an arrray of 6 arrays of `char[5]`. The error seems to indicate your last element, but it actually indicates the end of the array definition.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got a little lost with the tutorial
He did char somearray[5][5] = {{'T','h','o','s','e'}, {'c','h','i','c','k'}};
why is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your compiler seems a little stupid.

`{'L','i','a','m','z'}` is ok, but `{'M','a','r', 't', 'i', 'n'}` is too long for `char[5]`.

Comment: I considered the compiler as stupid here because it pointed the wrong position as containing some error and confused the user.